# How to update the WHERE clause to select identical data?

Tags: mysql, where-clause

```
CREATE TABLE `schedule` (
  `id` smallint(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `aircraftType` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
//...other fields
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=5611 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `aircrafts` (
  `id` smallint(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `aircraftType` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
//...other fields
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=5611 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

**SAMPLE CONTENT OF DB TABLES:**

Table "Schedule"

```
aircraftType = "320"
```

Table "Aircrafts"

```
aircraftType = "A320"
aircraftType = "A330"
```

**Query:**

```
SELECT *
FROM Schedule F, Aircrafts A
WHERE F.aircraftType = A.aircraftType;
```

How to update this query in such a way that aircratf types "320" and "A320" would be considered as similar in the WHERE clause?

Comment: Shoudnt you update the column for identical data?

Comment: @Mihai No, I only need to select identical data,without further updates.

Answer (score 1):

```
 SELECT *
FROM Schedule F, Aircrafts A
WHERE F.aircraftType = A.aircraftType LIKE CONCAT('%', F.aircraftType, '%')
```

OR

```
LIKE CONCAT('\"','%', F.aircraftType, '%','\"')-added double quotes.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try cutting of first char with [SUBSTRING()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring) :

```
SELECT *
FROM Schedule F, Aircrafts A
WHERE F.aircraftType = SUBSTRING(A.aircraftType, 2)
```

Or like @Mihai suggested, just put `%` on field that hasn't have `A` in it :

```
SELECT *
FROM Schedule F, Aircrafts A
WHERE CONCAT('%', F.aircraftType) LIKE A.aircraftType
```

But best solution would be to update data for identical relation string.